# Expandable Recycler View data mess up issue

Tags: android

Why expandable recycler view data is mess up when collapse or expand or scroll the recycler view . I also used setIsRecyclable to false  to the ViewHolder but still got same issue,
Please tell if someone know solution,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `adapter.notifydatasetchanged();` after adding the data